# How can I merge two trigger functions into one, in apps script?

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets

I have two pieces of script that both remove text from a Google sheet. Both scripts are on their own trigger when sheet is updated, but theyre both trying to edit the same cell and its only applying one of the functions.

Oringinal cell text example:
From: Leigh-on-sea, ss9, UK
Building No. Street & Postcode: 123 street address UK
Distance: 0.7m
Duration: 4 min

Function to remove text BEFORE "Postcode: "

```
function removeTags() {
  var column = 11
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (var n in data) {
    if (data[n][0] == '') { continue };// if cell empty then continue
    var str = data[n][0].toString();
    var location = str.indexOf("Postcode: ");
    if (location != -1) {
      data[n][0] = str.substring(location + 10, str.length - 1);//remove everything BEFORE Postcode: 
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(data);// update sheet with new data
}
```

Function to remove text AFTER "Distance: "

```
function removeTags(){
  var column = 11
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for(var n in data){
    if(data[n][0]==''){continue};// if cell empty then continue
    var str = data[n][0].toString();
    data[n][0]= str.substring(0,str.indexOf("Distance: "));//remove everything after Distance: 
  }
  sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow(),1).setValues(data);// update sheet with new data
}
```

Both functions work as expected when run separately, but when a new enrty is sent to the sheet, it only applies the first trigger/script. I need to merge the scripts together for a single trigger.

I tried editing a bit of the script a few way to figure it out myself, but failed.

Comment: I'm not sure SO is a good fit for this question, so it might get closed, but as a tip: These are doing almost the exact same thing and the only difference I can see is in the couple lines immediately following `var str`. You should be able to combine them. The second is a little cleaner and I'd do it first. The only catch is that instead of modifying `data[n][0]` you're going to want to set `str` to that result instead, so that `str` is updated (without everything after Distance) before going into the analysis for postcode. And then do the postcode work and finally set data[n][0] when done.

Comment: Yes I'm sure there's a better way to achieve the same goal... I just need to trim both sides of an address, but I don't really know what I'm doing with Java

Comment: You just need to combine the two like this: `str.substring(str.indexOf('Postcode'),str.indexOf('Distance'));`. Note that this is without checking if either of the required substrings exists (Postcode, or Distance, or either of the two).

Comment: I tried altering it, but didn't work   `
 {
    if (data[n][0] == '') { continue };// if cell empty then continue
    var str = data[n][0].toString();
    var location = str.substring(str.indexOf(“Postcode: “),str.indexOf(“Distance: “));
if (location != -1) {
      data[n][0] = str.substring(location + 10, str.length - 1);//remove everything BEFORE Postcode: 
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(data);// update sheet with new data
}

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion: Use `slice` instead of `substring`

@FiddlingAway's suggestion is valid; you would have to combine both of your functions as only one onEdit trigger will apply to the cell being modified. How I approached this is to slice the string and remove the text before and after the address and I've slightly modified your script to do that.

Do try this out:

```
function removeTags() {
  var column = 11
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (var n in data) {
    if (data[n][0] == '') { continue };// if cell empty then continue
    var str = data[n][0].toString();
    var startLocation = str.indexOf("Postcode: ")+10; //returns the index of "Postcode: " + 10
    var endLocation = str.indexOf("Distance: "); //Returns the index of "Distance: "
    if (startLocation != -1) {
      //The method below slices the string based on index stored in both startLocation and endLocation
      data[n][0] = str.slice(startLocation, endLocation)
    }
    
  }
  
  sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(data);// update sheet with new data
}
```

Note, however, that your script modifies **all rows in the column** whenever a new value is added if it's set up as a trigger.

If you would like the script to only modify and check just the last row, change both:

```
var data = sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
//and 
sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(data);
```

to:

```
var data = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), column).getValues();
//and
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), column).setValues(data);
```

### Reference:

- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: Hi @SB Promo Vids, was the answer above able to fix your issue?